# Can`t create a new conversation by skype bot

Tags: java, botframework, skype

I trying to create a new conversation with person or group of persons, so I create a Bearer token for authentication and add it to header as bearer token (in postman).

So on the next step I create a json script that, theoretically, can create a new conversation. I trying to create a conversation with several person or with only one (for it I added a several person to members or one and change flag isGroup to true or false).

This is a example of json for 1 person:

```
{
    "bot": {
        "id": "<app id>",
        "name": "<bot name>"
    },
    "isGroup": false,
    "members": [
       {
            "id": "<member id>",
            "name": "<member name>"
        }
    ],
    "topicName": "Hello there!"
}
```

Member id is correct for all members that I trying to add in a new conversation.

And the next response I get always:

```
{
    "id": "8:live:<skype account name>"
}
```

For group conversation I get the this live skype name for first person that I added. All requests was send to https://skype.botframework.com/v3/conversations or https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/v3/conversations and response always same.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Also if I add Activity in body like:

```
"activity": 
    { 
        "type": "message", 
        "from": 
        { 
            "id": "<app-id>", 
            "name": "<bot name>" 

        },
        "recipient": 
        { 
            "id": "<member id>", 
            "name": "<member name>" 
        }, 
        "text": "HI" 
    }
```

I get next response:

```
{ 
    "error": 
    { 
        "code": "ServiceError", 
        "message": "Unknown" 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please do not post code in comments, even if it's just JSON. Edit the question to include the formatted JSON.

Comment: Why did you remove information from your question?

Comment: I moved information into question.

Comment: Look at the edit history. Your last edit was to remove 470 characters: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56577717/revisions

Comment: Yes. I still working on this.

Comment: Are you using Skype or Skype for Business?

Comment: @KyleDelaney, I`m using skype

Comment: You added the "java" tag. Are you building a bot with the Java Bot Builder SDK? Or are you using the REST API?

Comment: @KyleDeleney, I'm using Java Bot Builder SDK, but then I send response by this SDK I get same response, that I describe above. So I try build json request by myself and using Skype Bot framework instruction for creating a group this several user, and get the same response then I used SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Skype only allows one conversation between any two given users, what looks like a simple user ID is actually enough for the Bot Framework to identify the conversation. Some channels, Skype included, allow more than one ID format. In the case of Skype, each conversation can be identified in two ways:

- < number >:< Skype screen name >
- < number >:< base64 string >

For example, when I create a conversation in Skype, I get the ID `8:kyle-delaney`. I can use that to send a message to the conversation with the following endpoint:

```
https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/v3/conversations/8:kyle-delaney/activities
```

However, when my bot receives a message from the user, both the conversation ID and the "from" ID will be `29:1CpqzpVMMhfi_2nyS1g2mfHaCxnvGL0sF8LbnGadyR_Y`. So I can also send a message to the same conversation using this endpoint:

```
https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/v3/conversations/29:1CpqzpVMMhfi_2nyS1g2mfHaCxnvGL0sF8LbnGadyR_Y/activities
```

Comment: I know how I can send a message to the conversation. My question was "How can I create a group conversation between several users using skype bot?".

Comment: If using skype bot framework instruction for creating conversation, then in my json I must set true for isGroup field and add users that I want to add in field members, so how can I get theirs ids for creating a group conversation?

Comment: I used next resources for creating a self written json https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#create-conversation

Comment: But then I try send a json, that I wrote (see json above), I get response from skype, that doesn't contain group id, but contain id of conversation for first user in members list.

Comment: I think I describe my problem not clear. Sorry for that. I mean that I can't create a GROUP conversation between two users using skype bot. For that I set flag isGroup conversation in true and add needed users to members list(I get ids for that by sending request from each user and get this id from activity, I think that I do something wrong).

Comment: I recommend updating your question so that you're asking about what you really want to know, and I recommend being more clear in the future. To answer your question, [Skype does not allow bots to start group conversations](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/2254#issuecomment-281543110).

Comment: But, why on this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#create-conversation

Comment: We have a instruction to create a skype conversation? What if I know a user skype login or get it by request, then user start dialog with skype bot. Can I create in this case a group dialog?

Comment: The REST API you linked is not channel-specific. Some channels don't even have group conversations, so would you expect to be able to create a group conversation in that case? Every operation documented has to be tested on your specific channel to see if it works or not. It doesn't matter what credentials your bot has access to, Skype doesn't allow bots to create group conversations. The best you can do is ask the user to create a group conversation.

Comment: I answered the question you asked. Please remember to upvote and accept my answer. Feel free to ask new questions on new question pages.